# What is the iframe section doing in the portal page

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have just noticed that in every portal page(Visualforce), there is an iframe section at the end of each page:

```
<iframe tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" title="Intentionally blank" name="lpSS_56567954057" id="lpSS_56567954057" src="https://lpcdn.lpsnmedia.net/le_secure_storage/3.3.0.2-release_294/storage.secure.min.html?loc=https%3A%2F%2Fcortexfull-auscript.cs84.force.com&amp;site=70456157&amp;env=prod" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;"></iframe>
```

But I really don't understand what it is doing. I am pretty sure it is not impacting our business scenarios but I need to prove to my business team.

Comment: Looks like a tracking flag used for analytics